# How to reinstall GRUB to a different boot drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I have an SSD and a Hard Disk. I have Windows installed on the SSD and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a HDD partition.

So what I want is I have no idea on which device the bootloader is installed but what I need is I want the SSD to be free of GRUB and it should be installed on the HDD so only when I change boot priority in BIOS it will boot to Ubuntu and all other times it will boot straight to Windows

BTW I have an OG BIOS not a UEFI one and both disks run on MBR

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do `sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc`.

With navigation through TAB, at least you get this window (of course with your drive names'):

```
  ┌───────────────┤ Konfiguriere grub-pc ├───────────────┐                                                            
  │ Geräte für die GRUB-Installation:                     │                                                            
  │                                                       │                                                            
  │    [*] /dev/sda (120034 MB; SanDisk_SDSSDA120G)       │                                                            
  │    [ ] - /dev/sda1 (37580 MB; /)                      │                                                            
  │    [ ] /dev/sdb (1000204 MB; WDC_WD10JPVX-22JC3T0)    │                                                            
  │                                                       │                                                            
  │                                                       │                                                            
  │                        <Ok>                           │                                                            
  │                                                       │                                                            
  └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

There, you can choose your desired harddrive.

Comment: No, it asks about command line and linux parameters, and then quits doing nothing.

Comment: This is only for systems in bios mode non gpt partitions

Answer (score 2):

### Install GRUB on Ubuntu disk, Windows is on the other.

Install GRUB using Terminal on a Live USB.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdxy /mnt

sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdx
```

Where sdxy is the partition on the Ubuntu HDD where /boot/grub.grub.cfg is located.

And sdx is the Ubuntu HDD.

Try a `sudo update-grub` after the install. If your Windows also boots in BIOS mode, it should add Windows to your grub menu, without affecting the Windows boot manager.

Best to back things up before proceeding.

Comment: Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.

Comment: Me too. Brand new laptop worked for 3 months, then stopped booting. Now I get the same message about no BIOS Boot Partition.

Comment: I also had to say `-d /mnt/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi` because my rescue image was `i386` and did not contain the required `x86_64` stuff that grub needed.

Comment: This is effectively from: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System
Note: I also had to mount the EFI partition (/dev/sdx1 for me) to /mnt/boot/efi

Comment: There's no command `update`. Maybe you meant `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: @Mikko Rantalainen: Noted, thanks.